# enctype = "multipart/form-data" works different between ie9 and chrome

Tags: javascript, forms, cross-domain, multipartform-data

I want to post some data to another domain with the enctype equal to multipart/form-data, because I want the unmodified data in the server side.
Here is my test code:

```
<textarea name="txt" rows="20" cols="80">
</textarea>
<script>
function x_domain_post(url, data)
{
    var dd = document.createElement('div');
    var ifrname = "client_proxy";
    dd.innerHTML = "<iframe id='" + ifrname + "' name='" + ifrname + "' width=0 height=0 ></iframe>";
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(dd);
    var ifr = document.getElementById(ifrname);

    var f = document.createElement('form');
    f.action = url;
    f.method = "post";
    f.enctype = "multipart/form-data";
    f.target = ifr.name;
    f.innerHTML = f.innerHTML + "<textarea name='request'>default</textarea>";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(f);
    document.getElementsByName("request")[0].value=data;
    f.submit()
    setTimeout(function(){document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].removeChild(f);}, 1000);
}

</script>
<button onclick="x_domain_post('http://192.168.232.128/add', document.getElementsByName('txt')[0].value)">
```

The request in chrome is:

```
...
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary9zCD31eJSHkdb8ul
...
------WebKitFormBoundary9zCD31eJSHkdb8ul
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="request"

a

b

o
------WebKitFormBoundary9zCD31eJSHkdb8ul--
```

But in IE9:

```
POST /add HTTP/1.1
...
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
...
request=a%0D%0A%0D%0Ab%0D%0A%0D%0Ao
```

Any of your help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this help?

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1273-Setting-Form-EncType-Dynamically-To-Multipart-Form-Data-In-IE-Internet-Explorer-.htm

> Apparently in IE, you have to set the
>   "encoding" of the form rather than the
>   "enctype". The good news is, you can
>   set both values without concern and
>   this will take care of the problem